# CMake keep crashing

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, cmake

I'm trying to install cmake on Window 7 32 bit OS. When I try running, it keeps crashing. Installation works fine. I initially installed and used it on Windows XP, and it worked fine. So it's only giving 'me' problems on windows 7. Likely, someone outthere will have an idea. Thx... See picture below...

[image: Cmake crush sample]

Comment: 2.8.10. Tried 2.8.9 as well. Same error...

Comment: I recommend you to try to profile cmake-gui with the Dependancy Walker tool at http://www.dependencywalker.com/. It might be able to reveal you issues with dlls that would fail to load, or import functions not found... etc

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with your system C++ runtimes or you have some old version of Qt dlls installed in your path.